# Rasterizer is not working properly

Tags: qgis, rasterization

[image]I am working with the following dataset: "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HRUhNwsnxc64KYYQ4GqttbzvUleEl0uI?usp=sharing" . I would like to rasterize the vulnerability data. However, when I running rasterizer the raster data shows values for .23-.735, but vector data has .16-.735. Why is this problem occurring?

Comment: Could you please add screenshots of the dialog with your chosen settings?

Comment: added picture and the output extent is calculate from layer>reprojected.